# Unable to disable civivolunteer

Tags: civivolunteer

When I go to Administer->Extensions and try to disable CiviVolunteer (version 4.7.21-2.2.3) I get a DB Table Not Found. Here is the backtrace:

```
#0 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(187): 
CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): 
call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error-
>__construct("DB Error: no such table", -18, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TRIGGER 
civicrm_value_volunteer_information_6_after_insert after inser...")
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error-
>__construct(-18, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TRIGGER 
civicrm_value_volunteer_information_6_after_insert after inser...")
#5 [internal function](): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -18, 
NULL, NULL, "CREATE TRIGGER 
civicrm_value_volunteer_information_6_after_insert after inser...", 
"DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(224): 
call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:8))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR-
>__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#8 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR-
>raiseError(NULL, -18, NULL, NULL, "CREATE TRIGGER 
civicrm_value_volunteer_information_6_after_insert after inser...", 
"DB_Error", TRUE)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common-
>raiseError(-18, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1146 ** Table 
'vahcrm.civicrm_value_volunteer_information_6' doesn't exist")
#10 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli-
>mysqliRaiseError()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli-
>simpleQuery("CREATE TRIGGER 
civicrm_value_volunteer_information_6_after_insert after inser...")
#12 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-            
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2446): DB_common-
>query("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_volunteer_information_6_after_insert 
after inser...")
#13 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1635): 
DB_DataObject->_query("CREATE TRIGGER 
civicrm_value_volunteer_information_6_after_insert after inser...")
#14 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(369): DB_DataObject-
>query("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_volunteer_information_6_after_insert 
after inser...")
#15 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1318): CRM_Core_DAO-
>query("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_volunteer_information_6_after_insert 
after inser...", FALSE)
#16 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/SqlTriggers.php(225): 
CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("CREATE TRIGGER 
civicrm_value_volunteer_information_6_after_insert after inser...", 
(Array:0), TRUE, NULL, FALSE, FALSE)
#17 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/SqlTriggers.php(171): 
Civi\Core\SqlTriggers->enqueueQuery("CREATE TRIGGER 
civicrm_value_volunteer_information_6_after_insert after inser...")
#18 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/SqlTriggers.php(70): 
Civi\Core\SqlTriggers->createTriggers((Array:15), NULL)
#19 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(2035): 
Civi\Core\SqlTriggers->rebuild(NULL, FALSE)
#20 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(392): 
CRM_Core_DAO::triggerRebuild()
 content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Manager.php(342): 
CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches(TRUE)
#22 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php(200): 
CRM_Extension_Manager->disable((Array:1))
#23 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(447): 
CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->postProcess()
#24 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): 
CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#25 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): 
CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next", 
"Next")
#26 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): 
CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), 
"next")
#27 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): 
HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next")
#28 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): 
HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#29 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(398): 
CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#30 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(156): 
CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit(64, NULL)
#31 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(121): 
CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#32 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): 
CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->run((Array:3), NULL)
#33 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): 
CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:16))
#34 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): 
CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#35 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1216): 
CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#36 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#37 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): 
call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#38 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): 
 WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#39 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): 
WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#40 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/wp-admin/admin.php(224): 
do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
```

And I get this on the screen.

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: no such table
Error Details
Return to home page.

Ideas?